# How do I add a file to the _layouts folder and have it recognized in the website?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to add a file Ratings.js to the ../TEMPLATE/LAYOUTS folder for my sharepoint solution, if I just paste the file in there, how can I make it work with my sharepoint application, do I have to add it in the file to the site settings somewhere?

I cant reach it by going to http://site/_layouts/Ratings.js even though its in there.

Comment: What type of SharePoint object will be utilizing the js?"

Comment: did you try an iisreset?

Comment: The ratings controller that comes out of the box with sharepoint. for some reason my program cant find that _layouts/Ratings.js file, and i cant find it either

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the Ratings.js file exists, but is not accessible  via browser.  Can you browse other files (js or ASPX in that directory?

Comment: Yes I can see other aspx files in that directory